# Extending a C# interface with common logic without using Extension Methods

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, interface, extension-methods

Is there a way to extend an interface without using Extension Methods?

If I define some interface with a couple of get/set strings for example :

```
public interface IMyItem
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like add some simple validation to these interfaces, but without having
to re-define the logic or force some form of inheritance.

Currently I'm using Extension Methods, like this :

```
public static class MyItemExtensions
{
    public static bool ERROR(this IMyItem item)
    {
        return item.TITLE_ERROR() || item.DESCRIPTION_ERROR();
    }

    public static bool TITLE_ERROR(this IMyItem item)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title);
    }

    public static bool DESCRIPTION_ERROR(this IMyItem item)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description);
    }
}
```

Doing this works and I can have:

```
public class Item : IMyItem
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public static class app
{
    public static void go()
    {
        var item = new Item
        {
            Title = "My Item Title", 
            Description = ""
        };

        Console.log(item.ERROR());
    }
}
```

But I'd prefer `ERROR`, `TITLE_ERROR` & `DESCRIPTION_ERROR` 
to be get/sets - Is there a way to achieve the same but expose
Get/Set properties rather than Extension Methods?

### Update 11/06/2014

As many have suggested, an `abstract` class would be an obvious solution based on the example, but the types need to implement **multiple** interfaces.

While it may be possible to arrange the inheritance it's an unnecessary complication and restriction on the types.

The added benefit of using Extension Methods for validation on these interfaces allows for context specific & shared logic to be used, via namespacing.

Multiple `ERROR(this IMyItem item)` Extension Methods could be defined for the interface, on different namespaces.  One that checks Both the `TITLE_ERROR` and `DESCRIPTION_ERROR` and another might only test one of the properties.  Then, depending on the context, the relevant namespace can be referenced and the shared validation for that item be executed.

I'll look at Microsoft's validator, but it looks rather verbose and I really wanted these states as properties for type, as it makes the code that uses them much easier to use.

Additionally, these are very simple examples, some of the validation much more complex and some cases require interaction with other web services - albeit against a cache of web service data within the AppDomain.

> Currently these `interface` Extension Methods feel like the best solution.

Comment: Not really. But why do you care? Properties are little more than sugar around a getter/setter method.

Comment: Maybe you can use an `abstract` class instead, make the two properties `cTitle` and `cDescription` abstract, and then have the error methods in the same abstract class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending an Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963542/extending-an-interface)

Comment: @TzahMama I don't think so. The linked question is about implementing two interface methods with the same signature in a single class. This one is about code sharing.

Comment: @Luaan As you say, get/set vs. Extension Methods are little more than syntax sugar.  In this case I'd just rather it a little sweater.

Answer (score 5):

I think a proper solution would be to use an `abstract class` instead of an `interface`.

What you share here is a common validation logic which will be valid for any class implementing `IMyItem`. As so, i'd recommand you create an `abstract class` as a base for all items, that way they can all reuse that validation code. You can even make those properties virtual, so one could extend that validation code:

```
public abstract class ItemBase : IMyItem
{
    public string cTitle { get; set; }
    public string cDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Error 
    { 
      get { return TitleError || DescriptionError; } 
    }

    public virtual bool TitleError 
    { 
      get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(cTitle); } 
    }

    public virtual bool DescriptionError 
    { 
      get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(cDescription); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuval!  As you say, an `abstract` would be applicable, but the types must implement multiple interfaces and a deep inheritance would add unnecessary complication to types.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How is that deep inheritance? Types can implement multiple interfaces disregarding deriving from a common base class

Comment: Of course, this isn't deep, it's simplified example of a single item / interface / abstract class.  

However, IRL the higher level classes implement any number of these interfaces, each of which have these Extension Methods. 

In order to accommodate all these different types I would need different abstract classes.  As a class can't inherit from more than one of abstract class I would have to add some form of inheritance depth.

Which adds unnecessary complication to the types.

Comment: I see. Well, next time i suggest you post your IRL problem / code so we can answer according to actual problem.

Comment: Will do!  Thanks again tho @yuval-itzchakov :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're reinventing the wheel.  Microsoft already created a fairly [good validation framework](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) that does not require Entity Framework or MVC. Simply add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and the `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // required if you use the MetdataType attribute
        TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
            new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyItem),
                typeof(IMyItemValidation)),
            typeof(MyItem));


        var item = new MyItem();
        var context = new ValidationContext(item, 
          serviceProvider: null, 
          items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(item, context, results);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (var validationResult in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(IMyItemValidation))]
    public class MyItem : IMyItem
    {
        public string cTitle { get; set; }
        public string cDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMyItem
    {
        string cTitle { get; set; }
        string cDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMyItemValidation
    {
        [Required]
        string cTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        string cDescription { get; set; }
    }

    /* 

    // alternatively you could do either of these as well:
    // Derive MyItem : MyItemBase

    // contains the logic on the base class
    public abstract MyItemBase
        [Required]
        public string cTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string cDescription { get; set; }
    }

    // or

    // Derive MyItem : MyItemBase
    // contains the logic on the base class using MetadataType
    [MetadataType(typeof(IMyItemValidation))]
    public abstract MyItemBase
        public string cTitle { get; set; }
        public string cDescription { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Output

> The cTitle field is required.
>
> the cDescription field is required.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  I'll look at the validator, but it looks rather verbose - I was after removing parentheses, not adding an additional type for the validation result.  - I've also updated my question.